# InvalidMountException while loading model from mlflow-registry in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, mlflow

I am trying to load my spark model that I have registered using mlflow in databricks ( referring  this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/mlflow/model-registry-example#load-versions-of-the-registered-model-using-the-api)

My Code is :

```py
model_uri = "models:/{model_name}/{stage_name}".format(
   model_name=model_name,stage_name=stage_name)

model = mlflow.spark.load_model(model_uri )
```

But this gives me following error :

```
: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException: 
  Error while using path /databricks/mlflow-registry/run-id/models/spark-model/sparkml 
  for resolving path '/run-id/models/spark-model/sparkml' 
  within mount at '/databricks/mlflow-registry'.
```

(Note: `artifact_path` passed by me while registering model was 'spark-model')

How can this error be resolved?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this @PALAK?